# How to turn on PHP's register_globals for local scripts only?

Tags: php, linux, shell, scripting, ubuntu

I am using php as a command line scripting language for executing various system commands.

How can I turn on register_globals locally - to a single script only perhaps? Can this be done via the script itself?

I would prefer not to change global settings if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the directive or the php.ini file in command line:

```
C:\>php -?
[...]
  -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
[...]
  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
```

E.g.:

```
php -d register_globals=1 do-stuff.php
```

Of course, in the long term it's better to simply fix the script. Otherwise, you can find the some day the script won't even run after a system upgrade.

If you are using the shebang syntax, you may need to write a wrapper for PHP so you can provide more than one argument.

Comment: The shebang in this case can be `#!/usr/bin/php -dregister_globals=1` - a limited concatenation of parameters is supported there.

Answer (score 2):

You can always call [`extract()`](http://ch.php.net/extract) on any array you'd like to have "registered". You should checkout the additional parameters in the manual, it lets you control wheter it should overwrite variables or prefix them.

Note that `register_globals` has been deprecated, there are certain security concerns you should consider when doing things like this.